# jQuery: $(this).attr('id') not find id of element - undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get id and just simply alert it onclick although is does just "undefined"...
Can you help me out?
important Code:
HTML:

`<img src="/pictures/picture.jpg" class="r-gal-photo" id='1' onclick="alertme()" />`

jQuery:

```
function alertme() {
alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

Can you see the problem? I can't... 
My bad: 
I'm sorry, I wanted to simplify the code and I did not realize that I used "alert()" as name for customized function.

Comment: Why don't you bind the event handler by using jQuery? Also you are  _recursively_ calling the alert function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem to fix is the function name, which I suspect is different in your actual code because otherwise you wouldn't have gotten as far as you have.

You've used an old-school "onclick" attribute to associate the function with the element. Nothing assures that `this` will be bound to the element as you expect. You could either change the element:

Better would be to use jQuery to bind the handler:

```
$("#1").on("click", function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: ``this.id`` will work? or we have to use ``$(this).attr(id)``?

Comment: I can not use it... In my real code there is undefined number of object with the same function but different code in brackets and each has different id. So I used this code as example of my own script I wanted to use instead of real code. Because this has the same problem and is easier. Anyway... My great apologiez for not seeing that I used "alert" as name for custom function...

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

is, as others said - the context of the `this` keyword.

`this` refers to the DOM element (as you thought it does) in the CALL ITSELF, but once you called `alertme()` it is not defined in its scope.
To see it you can look at this JS:

```
function alertme(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    console.log(this);
}
```

and this HTML markup:

```
<img src="/pictures/picture.jpg" class="r-gal-photo" id='abc' onclick="console.log(this); alertme()" />
```

And you will see that you get in the console first the element, then in the alert 'undefined' and then in the console the *window*.

#### To fix it

you can either simply specify the meaning of `this` in the call, using javaScript's [Function.prototype.call() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

Change only in the HTML the markup to

```
<img src="/pictures/picture.jpg" class="r-gal-photo" id='abc' onclick="alertme.call(this)" />
```

and it will work with the your alertme().

OR you can just pass `this` into `alertme` like so:

```
function alertme(elem){
    alert($(elem).attr('id'));
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="/pictures/picture.jpg" class="r-gal-photo" id='abc' onclick="alertme(this)" />
```

Sources:

[Nice article to understand 'this' in jQuery](https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified)

[this in JS binded by on markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handler's_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value)

Comment: I can NOT use it as I wrote sereval times to comment. The real code (this is a simplified example) has different text in the brackets so I can't write there "elem" or what things you mostly wrote me here. I need to make it alert its own id without using the in-brackets coding. Because the brackets are full of something different. I want it to alert the id just to know that it found its id and not "undefined".

Comment: @AdamOpalecký Please explain - I do not understand what you mean by "different code in the brackets" - which brackets and where? The angle/round/curly brackets? (if round - in definition or call of the alertme?)
It works for every element, without changing the JS. Add `<button id="bbb" onclick="alertme(this)">` to the HTML and when you click the button it will alert "bbb", but if you click the image it will alert "abc". Please explain how is that not general enough? Why is "alertme(this)" problematic but "alertme()" isn't?

Comment: I've just added another (better) fix, which I learned just now thanks to @JefréN.